# AntiSamy properties issue with break line

Tags: java, antisamy

I'm trying to use AntiSamy in java but I'm getting problem with break line.

This is the value from GUI: 
`First line\r\nSecond line`

This is the value with org.owasp.validator.html.CleanResults: 
`First line\nSecond line`

When I try to compare the answer is false.

```
value.equals(cr.getCleanHTML());
```

My Properties:

```
<directives>
    <directive name="omitXmlDeclaration" value="true"/>
    <directive name="omitDoctypeDeclaration" value="true"/>
    <directive name="maxInputSize" value="5000"/>
    <directive name="useXHTML" value="true"/>
    <directive name="formatOutput" value="false"/>
    <directive name="preserveSpace" value="true" />

    <directive name="embedStyleSheets" value="false"/>
</directives>
```

Any idea?

Comment: So do you just want to keep "\r"? What for?

Comment: Yes is that the goal.